# Delete lines in a file based on first row

Tags: terminal, multiple-columns

I try to work on a whole series of txt files (actually .out, but behaves like a space delimited txt file). I want to delete certain lines in the text, based on the output compared to the first row.

So for example:

```
ID VAR1 VAR2
1 8 9
2 4 1
3 3 2
```

I want to delete all the lines with VAR1 < 0,5.

I found a way to do this manually in excel, but with 350+ files, this is going to be a long night, there are sure ways to do this more effective.. I worked on this set of files already in terminal (OSX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical job for `awk`, the venerable language for file manipulation.

What `awk` does is match each line in a file to a condition, and provide an action for it. It also allows for easy elementary parsing of line columns. In this case, you want to test whether the second column is less than 0.5, and if so not print that line. Otherwise, print the line (in effect this removes lines for which the variable is less than 0.5.

Your variable is in column 2, which in awk is referred to as $2. Each full line is referred to by the variable $0.

So you would do something like this:

```
{    if ($2 < 0.5) {
     }
     else {
     print $0
     }
}
```

Or something like that, I haven't used awk for a while. The above code is an awk script. Apply it on your file, and redirect the output to a new file (which will have all the lines not satisfying the condition removed).

Comment: In the interest of completeness, to save you some time, simply put that code in any text file, and then do: `gawk -f <code_file> <orig_input> > <filtered_input>`

Comment: And if you thought `gawk` must be GNU's version of `awk`, you would be right.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Now, if I want to do this with multiple variables, should I use the '&&' syntax? I saw that in another thread.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Yes, the `awk` operator for logical AND is `&&`. There are some nice tutorials for `awk` online. For example see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-12